# Cannot read property of 'get' $http inside a nested function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get

I get the following error

> angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at Object.DataService.getDataFromAPI

Here is the where I am messing up the $HTTP.get. Any idea of what I am doing wrong or how to fix it? **I think the problem is passing the $HTTP into the nested function.**

(function (module) {
    'use strict';

```
DataService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
function DataService($http, $q) {


var getDataFromAPI = function ($http) {


        $http.get("http://localhost:34183/myAPI")
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        });

    };
}
 return {
            getDataFromAPI: getDataFromAPI
};
}

    module.factory('DataService', DataService);

})(angular.module('ClassAPP'));
```

Here is my code showing the method works if i just embed the json directly in there which works fine.

```
 DataService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
 function DataService($http, $q) {

 var getDataFromAPI = function ($http) {
        return [{
                  "Grade": "A+",
                  "Class": {
                      "Subject": "Select Topics in Basket Weaving",
                      "Professor": "DJ Khaled"
                  }            
               }];
    };
return {
            getDataFromAPI: getDataFromAPI
};
}
module.factory('DataService', DataService);

})(angular.module('ClassAPP'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need return object inside factory

```
function DataService($http, $q) {


    var getDataFromAPI = function () {        

      return $http.get("http://localhost:34183/myAPI")
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;
            });

        };

      return {
           getDataFromAPI : getDataFromAPI 
       }
    }
```

Comment: sorry i am i left that out i think the issue is i cant the the $http into the method

Comment: You also need to return the $http service from the function: 

var getDataFromAPI = function() {
return $http.....

Comment: does the function need to have $http accepted as a parameter ?

Comment: you dont need pass $http as parametr you already injected it in service, as @Rob pointed you need return $http request object inside function,

Answer (score 1):

Can you write it like this?

```
app.factory("DataService", ["$http", function($http){
    return {
        getDataFromApi: function(url) {
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Usage**

```
getDataFromApi.getDataFromApi('/path/to/api/');
```

Comment: great post if all of my urls start with the following http://localhost:34183/api is there a way to say *this/api1 *this*/api2 etc.

ie if my calls are http://localhost:34183/api/myapi1
http://localhost:34183/api/myAPI2
http://localhost:34183/api/myoldAPI 

can i refactor out the left side of the api? like say THIS or the current route?